# Still not getting proper resolution (landscape, portrait) images back from the API

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Even if I update my client with checking in the "Non square media" option, I'm still getting squared image results from the API. When an image is not square sized, a white padding appears on the side of the picture to fill out the space. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: Sure, here's a landscape image, this is what I'm getting back from the images -> standard_resolution : https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xaf1/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/11326233_835900669860163_1951625767_n.jpg, and this is the thumnail version: https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xaf1/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/c180.0.719.719/11881674_494110720758952_1219626770_n.jpg